# Why aren't these two attributes being filtered for?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing an query that determines which courses were held in large lecture halls or auditorium type classrooms in Summer Quarter of 2016.

When I execute it, it successfully filters for the Classroom Types of either Large Lecture or Audio but it doesn't do the same for both Quarter and Year

**Sample Output:**

[image]

```
SELECT 
    CO.CourseID, CourseName AS Summer2016LectureHallOrAudiotoriumCourses, 
    ClassroomTypeName, QuarterName, [YEAR]
FROM
    tblCOURSE CO
JOIN 
    tblCLASS C ON CO.CourseID = C.CourseID
JOIN 
    tblQUARTER Q ON C.QuarterID = Q.QuarterID
JOIN 
    tblCLASSROOM CR ON C.ClassroomID = CR.ClassroomID
JOIN 
    tblCLASSROOM_TYPE CT ON CR.ClassroomTypeID = CT.ClassroomTypeID
WHERE 
    CT.ClassroomTypeName = 'Large Lecture Hall' 
    OR CT.ClassroomTypeName = 'Auditorium'
    AND Q.QuarterName = 'summer'
    AND C.[YEAR] = '2016'
```

Comment: try to put brackets like this `(CT.ClassroomTypeName = 'Large Lecture Hall' OR CT.ClassroomTypeName = 'Auditorium')`, give it try and let me know.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace following in your query.

`CT.ClassroomTypeName = 'Large Lecture Hall' OR CT.ClassroomTypeName = 'Auditorium'`

with

```
(CT.ClassroomTypeName = 'Large Lecture Hall' OR CT.ClassroomTypeName = 'Auditorium')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use `IN` clause instead of `OR` :

```
WHERE CT.ClassroomTypeName IN ('Large Lecture Hall', 'Auditorium') AND
      Q.QuarterName = 'summer' AND 
      C.[YEAR] = 2016 -- do not use single quote on numerical type
```